# Cant initialize NightOwl

Tags: android, android-night-mode

I'm working on a Calculator App for Android, I will implement **night mode** and I found this [project](https://github.com/ashqal/NightOwl).

In the readme it says that I have to init NightOwl in my Application Class with:

```
NightOwl.builder().defaultMode(0).create();
```

However, it wont let me init nightowl because it doesnt recognize **builder** method.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CROjv.png)

I would be glad if any of you could help me initializing NightOwl.

Comment: Are you using the newest version?

Comment: I'm using the one from readme `compile 'com.asha.nightowllib:nightowllib:0.2'`.

Comment: Nope, it still says `Cannot resolve symbol 'builder'`